# Connecting Matlab with an Android phone

Tags: android, matlab

I have a trading algorithm that engages financial markets.

It is written entirely in Matlab and it is fully automated. I'm using IB-Matlab to engage the markets.

I would like to be able to track my portfolio with my phone, and also include something like a killswitch to cease trading or sell all my positions.

Any advice or directions as to where I should start?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: MATLAB mobile app can connect to your MATLAB session running on a desktop. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mathworks.matlabmobile&hl=en Does that help?

Comment: My Matlab session will be running on a computer that is in a fixed location. 

I need to be able to access it remotely. Unfortunately I don't believe that the mobile app allows me to do this.

Comment: You need the IP address of the computer and run MATLAB connector in the desktop to be able to connect to it. When you are on public network this may not be the best way from security point. Alternatively you need to run your own web server and make it send commands to your MATLAB session.